# Errors while scraping email in one website with Scrapy

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to code an e-mail scraper, but i'm having problems.
This is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from email_validator import validate_email, EmailNotValidError
import requests
import pandas as pd

lista_star = ['vitalebarberiscanonico.it']
class MailSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'email'
    data = []

    def parse(self, response):
        links = LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()).extract_links(response)
        links = [str(link.url) for link in links]
        links.append(str(response.url))

        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link) 

    def parse_link(self, response):
        for word in self.reject:
            if word in str(response.url):
                return
         html_text = str(response.text)
         mail_list = re.findall('\w+@\w+\.{1}\w+', html_text)
         for email in mail_list:
             self.data.append({'email': email, 'link': str(response.url)})
            
    def get_info():
        process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        process.crawl(MailSpider, start_urls=lista_star)
        process.start()
        df = pd.DataFrame(MailSpider.data)
        df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='email')
        df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
        return df
    
    df = get_info()
```

I get: ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests and ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: vitalebarberiscanonico.it

So i tried:

```
    for link in links:
        parsed_url = urlparse(link)
        if not parsed_url.scheme:
            link = urlunparse(parsed_url._replace(scheme='http'))
        elif parsed_url.scheme not in ['http', 'https']:
            continue
        try:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link)
        except:
            link = link.replace('http', 'https')
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link)
```

But it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in you not having a [scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes) in your original url. Instead of having the url parsing code that you tried. You can just change the link's string itself to a http or https:

```py
lista_star = ['https://vitalebarberiscanonico.it/']
```